# How is highest posterior density interval estimated in this code snippet?

Tags: posterior, credible-interval, highest-density-region, julia

I found the following (Julia) implementation for estimating the highest posterior density interval from a posterior sample ([link](https://github.com/StatisticalRethinkingJulia/StatisticalRethinking.jl/blob/00a546fdd9c547a20c11dfb979f3881e33c77df5/src/hpdi.jl#L1-L13)). Below, I turn it into pseudocode for simplicity.

```
function hpdi(sample, alpha=0.11)
    n = length(sample)
    m = max(1, ceil(alpha * n)) # `ceil` returns an rounded up integer

    y = sort(sample) # sorts `sample` in ascending order
    a = y[1:m]
    b = y[(n - m + 1):n]
    _, i = findmin(b - a) # `i` is the index of the minimum value of `b - a`

    return [a[i], b[i]] # HPD interval
end
```

I think I understand what (each line of) the code accomplishes, but I don't quite understand what it does and why it works. Specifically, why do we need to sort the `sample` and index the 1st and the last `m` values? What is the point of the `findmin` line?

Comment: This does not appear to be computing an interval of highest posterior density.  Instead, it computes the *shortest interval containing at least $1-\alpha$ of the sample values.*

Comment: That makes sense. Wouldn't the shortest interval with $1 - \alpha$ values be the interval of a fixed mass with the highest density? I still don't understand how the code above finds it though. If you can explain it, I will accept the answer.